# Loading Page Issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to use the loading page from here http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/
because the personal website I was making is very poorly optimized and loads quite slowly

The loading page works fine if I make it a seperate page and then redirect to my home page like so:
http://matthewpiatetsky.com/cs103/demo/demo.html

However, I have also tried adding this same animation when I go directly to the page, and it does not work. I think this is because of the other js files present in the document.
http://matthewpiatetsky.com/cs103/

In the redirecting page the script is located here and it works.
http://matthewpiatetsky.com/cs103/demo/js/script.js

In the actual page the script is located here and it doesn't work.

http://matthewpiatetsky.com/cs103/js/matthew.js

The script declarations in the actual page look like this, so this script is called last. Calling it first breaks the page, so I'm guessing the 5-grid js is the problem.

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="css/5grid/init.js?use=mobile,desktop"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.formerize-1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/file/jquery.queryloader2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/matthew.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you edited your question to include a little more code so that in the future this question is still useful for people.  Your website will change, so your links won't work, but StackOverflow is forever. :-)

Comment: uh i could do that, but my mistake was simply not change a placeholder address in the src="" attribute..so there isn't much to learn from my mistake. If I had followed the instructions here correctly everything would have been fine haha. http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a plugin.  Your code tries to use the [QueryLoader2](https://github.com/Gaya/QueryLoader2) plugin on line 19 of Matthew.js, but you don't have this plugin included on your page.

Comment: hey sorry i put it back i accidentally took it out when i was trying to fix this problem, but that's not the problem. you can see i put it back and it still doesn't work

Comment: Well, now its a 404 for the plugin, so thats still the problem.

Comment: Yep, http://matthewpiatetsky.com/cs103/path/to/file/jquery.queryloader2.js is giving me a 404 - did you mean to leave `/path/to/file` in there?

Comment: What you need to do is check the console to debug your issues.  What browser are you using?

Comment: oh wow basic thank you i feel like a total idiot :(. i was doing this super late at night and missed something really basic (no pun intended haha). thank you!
(it works now)

Comment: @Matthew No worries, we've all done similar at some point in time. This was fairly simple to debug with the help of either Firebug (firefox) or Chrome's developer tools (F12) just go to the console, note that a resource didn't load correctly then go to the network tab and track down the problem url - then try browsing to it and see what happens :)